# Function call not working proparly (python)

Tags: python, debugging, methods

For input 1 to `self.trying`, the `set_jump()` method doesn't work. the program dosent execute the while loop in it

Code:

```py
jump = []
z = []


class jumps:
    def __init__(self, numberOfJumps, trying):
        self.numberOfJumps = numberOfJumps

        self.trying = int(trying)

    def setJumps(self):
        if self.trying == 1:
            # print("hello")
            self.set_jump()
        if self.trying == 2:
            self.get_jump()

        return ""

    def set_jump(self):

        counterSetJump = 0
        while counterSetJump < int(self.numberOfJumps):
            print("what was the distance the athlete jumped at jump number" + str(counterSetJump + 1))
            z.append(float(input()))
            counterSetJump += 1

        return ""

    def get_jump(self):
        counterGetJumps = 0
        while counterGetJumps < int(self.numberOfJumps):
            print(z[counterGetJumps])
            print("this is the jump for the " + str(counterGetJumps) + " time")
            counterGetJumps += 1
            return ""


class athlete:
    def __init__(self, name, yearsPro):
        self.name = name
        self.yearsPro = yearsPro

    def information(self):
        print("the athletes name is " + self.name)
        print("he as been active for " + str(self.yearsPro))
        return ""


a = []
b = []
i = 0
know = int(input("how many athletes you know the information for"))
while i < know:
    a.append(0)
    b.append(0)
    i = i + 1
j = 0
while j < know:
    a[j] = athlete(input("what is the athletes name?"), input("how many years as the athlete been active"))
    b[j] = jumps(input("how many jumps did the athlete jumped?"),
                 input("input 1 for settig and 2 for getting the jumps"))  # not getting called?
    b[j].setJumps()

    j = j + 1

infoFor = int(input("who do you want the info for"))
print(a[int(infoFor) - 1].information())
print(b[int(infoFor) - 1].get_jump())
```

Comment: You are adding a string and an integer in this line `print("what was the distance the athlete jumped at jump number" + i)`. It should raise en error. Replace that with `f"jump number {i}"` or `jump number %d" %i` for example. Also, you don't need to use while loops or manual increments, just use `for i in range(int(know)):` in the program and `for i in range(self.numberOfJumps):` in the class.

Comment: Your class isn't being called because your trying to increment through a list and use that as your instance. This in turn doesn't allow to if activate the `b[i].setJumps()` command.

Comment: sorry i am not sure what you mean here what should i change?
@Max

Answer (score 0):

**Check the code out**

```
jump = []
z = []


class jumps:
    def __init__(self, numberOfJumps, trying):
        self.numberOfJumps = numberOfJumps
        self.trying = int(trying)
        print("trying = "+str(self.trying))

    def setJumps(self) :
        if self.trying == 1:
            #print("hello")
            self.set_jump()
        if self.trying == 2:
            self.get_jump()
        print("Yes I have chnaged trying to = :"+str(self.trying))
        return ""

    def set_jump(self):
        print("set_jump finally called")
        i = 0
        while(i < int(self.numberOfJumps)):
            print("what was the distance the athlete jumped at jump number" + str(i))
            z.append(int(input()))
            i = i + 1

    def get_jump(self):
        i = 0
        while(i < int(self.numberOfJumps)):
            return z[i]
            i = i + 1


class athlete:
    def __init__(self, name, yearsPro):
        self.name = name
        self.yearsPro = yearsPro
    def information(self):
        print("the athletes name is " + self.name)
        print("he as been active for " + str(self.yearsPro))
        return ""



a = []
b = []
i = 0
know = int(input("how many athletes you know the information for"))
while(i < know):
    a.append(0)
    b.append(0)
    i = i + 1
j = 0
while(j <know):
    a[j] = athlete(input("what is the athletes name?"), input("how many years as the athlete been active"))
    b[j] = jumps(input("how many jumps did the athlete jumped?"),
                 input("input 1 for settig and 2 for getting the jumps")) #not getting called?
    b[j].setJumps()
    k=j
    for k in b:
        k.setJumps()
        #j=j+1
    j = j + 1

infoFor = int(input("who do you want the info for"))
print(a[int(infoFor) - 1].information())
print(b[int(infoFor) - 1].setJumps())
```

Comment: even when i inplument your chang i still get an error at line 65.
    j.setJumps()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setJumps'

Comment: @osenter this is the output which I am getting                                                                 how many athletes you know the information for1
what is the athletes name?d
how many years as the athlete been active1
how many jumps did the athlete jumped?1
input 1 for settig and 2 for getting the jumps1
who do you want the info for1
the athletes name is d
he as been active for 1

Comment: @osenter Actually in my machine it is running just fine

Comment: the cooment in which you describe what you get is what i get as well and its a problem. once i do setJumps i want it to start asking me what was the distance of the jumps not mopve on to who do you want the info for.

Comment: @osenter I have made few changes in your code. Check it out now it should work according to your need.

Comment: i have seen your code and unfortenetly is still didnt work . i use an ide called pycharm if that changes any thing.
what i can say is that i worked on the problem and now i think the issue is with get_jump().
the reason i say that is because i noticed nothing after the first jump is being printed.
see the changes i made to the code at the post

Comment: @osenter your problem was that set_jump was not getting called and in my code it's getting called. So where is the issue is left now.